# Error while deploying application in tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat7

Hi I am getting the following error while deplying application in tomcat:

```
Jul 25, 2013 5:04:43 PM org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResources cleanUp
WARNING: Failed to retrieve JNDI naming context for container [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/oms-inter-web]] so no cleanup was performed for that container
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [comp/env] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [comp].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:820)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResources.cleanUp(NamingResources.java:988)
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResources.stopInternal(NamingResources.java:970)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5494)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1585)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12213246/javax-naming-namenotfoundexception-name-comp-env-is-not-bound-in-this-context

Answer (score 0):

it may be because of previous applications are not properly undeployed from tomcat container.

**Stop the tomcat**, and then 
go to the tomcat conf directory `/<Tomcat root>/conf/Catalina/localhost` and clean the xml files in that directory. and restart the tomcat

Note: 
1. make a **backup** of those xml files before deleting, so that if this not works then you can restore it.

To do the same in Netbeans IDE

In Netbeans menu go to **Window->Services** , 
In the listed Services expand **Servers->->web applications->** right click on each application and choose **Undeploy**

Note: the tomcat need to be in running condition for this

Comment: Thanks for reply, There are no xml files in the directory specified. I have undeployed all the application and restarted the tomcat bu no clue on this

Answer (score 0):

I had exact the same problem and because Eclipse Tomcat was using the same working directory as Tomcat standalone I cannot started the standalone Tomcat properly. The solution was to change the Eclipse-Tomcat Config - Arguments - Working directory to something different than Tomcat/webapps.