# .War Works to deploy on Windows but fails to deploy on a Linux server (Tomcat 7)

Tags: java, linux, deployment, tomcat7, web-deployment

As title introduced, the .War file I'm trying to deploy by using Tomcat 7 is not working on a machine running Linux. It does work on Windows and is of course deployed with Tomcat 7.

I've tried to track down the issue alone & searched for related problems on the web including this forum with no success so far. That is why i created this thread asking for help / hints.

The error message I tracked down are the following:

```
Sep 14, 2015 4:46:05 PM org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResources cleanUp
WARNING: Failed to retrieve JNDI naming context for container [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SmartHomeReasoner]] so no cleanup was performed for that container
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [comp/env] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [comp].
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:819)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResources.cleanUp(NamingResources.java:986)
        at org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResources.stopInternal(NamingResources.java:968)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5676)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:141)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1256)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:692)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:217)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:213)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:610)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Looks like there's possibly a JNDI resource you're trying to fetch that isn't defined. Check for differences in your server's `server.xml` and `context.xml` maybe?

Comment: @CollinD, There are no differences I'm afraid.

Comment: This is a strange problem indeed then. Not sure if any of these help, but it looks like this is one of those generic errors that can mean any number of things http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20854848/tomcat-error-warning-failed-to-retrieve-jndi-naming-context-for-container or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17857038/error-while-deploying-application-in-tomcat-7

Comment: @CollinD, yeah I've tried those sadly, did not help.

Comment: Then I think all I can give you is an upvote and well-wishes. Sorry!

Comment: Do you have an app specific config file on your Windows machine? It will be located somewhere like `conf/catalina/localhost/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It were 2 problems actually causing this issue.

To solve the issue I had to:

*Check the web.xml VERY carefully after any misstakes like e.g. servlets that do not exist our already defined things e.g. driver being defined twice, meaning it's defined somewhere already AND also in the web.xml.

*Remove servlet in the ..\WEB-INF\lib folder of the project. E.g. javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar + javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar were removed in this case. 
NOTE I even had jars that can conflict with each other on project-level but still I was able to deployed successfully on Windows but not on Linux.

Trust me both of the things I mentioned can be a issue, most likely if you take over work from other devs that have done this miss.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue and synchronizing the Java version for the Maven build (from 1.8 to 1.10) and the running environment (1.10) solved it.