# Deploying .war file to tomcat server on linux

Tags: java, linux, deployment, server, tomcat7

The code and .war file work pretty well on localhost server (running Windows), but when we tried to deploy and start on a linux server, it failed and we got the following error.

> org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResources cleanUp WARNING: Failed to
>   retrieve JNDI naming context for container
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SmartHomeReasoner]]
>   so no cleanup was performed for that container
>   javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [comp/env] is not bound in
>   this Context. Unable to find [comp].
>           at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:819)
>           at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:167)
>           at org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResources.cleanUp(NamingResources.java:986)
>           at org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResources.stopInternal(NamingResources.java:968)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5676)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:141)
>           at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1256)
>           at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:692)
>           at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:217)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>           at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:213)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>           at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>           at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:610)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Have you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20854848/tomcat-error-warning-failed-to-retrieve-jndi-naming-context-for-container

Comment: Can you tell me what is the "comp/env" environment var?? Maybe it should release us about what is happening...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is available in the following link:

[.War Works to deploy on Windows but fails to deploy on a Linux server (Tomcat 7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32572737/war-works-to-deploy-on-windows-but-fails-to-deploy-on-a-linux-server-tomcat-7)

thanks for your kind attention.