# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [comp/env] is not bound in this Context

Tags: spring

I'm developing a spring application which uses tomcat server managed connection  pool.

I defined datasource in tag in context.xml of tomcat: (i am using spring 2.0.7) in context.xml:

```
<context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/irb_prod"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
    username="xxx"
     password="xxx"
     driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
     url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxx:1521:xxx"
     maxWait="1000"
     removeAbandoned="true"
     maxActive="5"
     maxIdle="5"
     removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
     logAbandoned="true"/>
</context>
```

And in my **ApplicationContext.xml(i.e in spring configuration file)**, the code is:

```
     <bean id="dataSource" 
     class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName">
    <value>java:comp/env/jdbc/irb_prod</value>
    </property>
    </bean>


 <!-- Transaction manager for a single JDBC DataSource -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" 
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource"><ref local="dataSource"/></property>
    </bean>
```

When the application starts, I get the following errors:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name java:/comp/env/mypool is not bound in this              Context
org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:803)
org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:159)
org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:158)
javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:132)
org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:88)
org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:130)
org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:155)
org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:93)
org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:105)
org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.lookupWithFallback(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java :197)
org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:184)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInit         ialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:736)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractAppli  cationContext.java:369)
org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init> (ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:123)
org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>  (ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:66)
MainServlet.init(MainServlet.java:21)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:541)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:383)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java :188)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:288)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: please structre the question properly so that it would be readable.

Comment: You have configured it as a global resource `java:jdbc/irb_prod` not as a resource local to your application. For this you will need to add a mapping to your app spefic deployment descriptor (i.e. context.xml).

Comment: can you post your web.xml here too? Because, you do need a `resource-ref` in case you specify the datasource/resource in `context.xml`

Answer (score 8):

I faced similar problem with tomcat and did the following in eclipse to solve it:

1. In the server's context.xml, included the jdbc connection details.
2. Stop the server
3. Clean the project(`Project --> Clean`) , the tomcat server (`Server--> Right Click --> Clean`) and Tomcat work directory (`Server--> Right Click--> Clean Tomcat Work Directory`).
4. Start the server and run.

Even after maintaining the details in context.xml, sometimes it might not get reflected.
In such cases follow step#3 and hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Please update your `web.xml` with the something similar to the following tag

```
<resource-env-ref>
  <description>DataSource
  </description>
  <resource-env-ref-name>
    dbc/irb_prod
  </resource-env-ref-name>
  <resource-env-ref-type>
    javax.sql.DataSource
  </resource-env-ref-type>
</resource-env-ref>
```

You need to refer this [link](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html) too for more information

Answer (score 0):

That will in case of Tomcat happen when you have for some reason dropped arbitrary servletcontainer-specific JARs such as jsp-api.jar, servlet-api.jar, catalina.jar, etc in webapp's /WEB-INF/lib. You should remove all servletcontainer-specific JARs from there, they do not belong there.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it seems that I had to first close my file explorer (FreeCommander XE) and then do the eclipse cleans (project and server), make sure to close any other programs that might have handles to deployed files even if the files are not open in those programs anymore

Answer (score 0):

**In Eclipse**: make sure you have the right context.xml file.
This especially valid when you have installed **multiple servers**.

In your Servers tab -> Right click on your deployed web module -> Browse Deployment Location -> ../conf/context.xml.
Make sure this is the file you want to be using.

I hope this saves you some time, as I wasted some time on it.

[image]

[image]