# Unable to deploy on tomcat after switching from ant to maven

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, tomcat8

I have a migrate a project from ant to maven.
It is an tomcat application.
But if I compile the war file with maven now a get an exception, after starting the war-file.

> javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [comp/env] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [comp].
>       at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:817)
>       at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:173)
>       at org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl.cleanUp(NamingResourcesImpl.java:994)
>       at org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl.stopInternal(NamingResourcesImpl.java:976)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:226)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5476)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:226)
>       at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.undeploy(ManagerServlet.java:1456)
>       at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:373)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:613)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1463)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
>       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

When I am compiling with ant the application starts without a problem.

This is my context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/AppControlServer">
    <Resource name="jdbc/App" auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="50" maxIdle="10" maxWait="4000"
    username="App" password="App"
    driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
    url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/App"/>
</Context>
```

The application is using hibernate, this is my hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:comp/env/jdbc/App</property>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">managed</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>
        <! -- entity mapping -->
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: check this link if this make any sense.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21527714/javax-naming-namenotfoundexception-name-comp-env-is-not-bound-in-this-context/23511532

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have only changed the build platform then compare the two war files and see what has changed. When you know what has changed it is easier to fix it.

My guess based on similar migrations is that you have resource files in the source folder (`src/main/java`). Maven doesn't copy files from the source folder, they should go in the resource folder (`src/main/resources`) instead. Be sure to preserve the directory structure if you move files!

Comment: The only difference I see is that the maven war contains an folder maven which contains the pom.xml and the pom.properties. And the MANIFEST.MF are different.

Comment: Odd. I assume that you have diffed the folders recursively with some tool, so that you are sure that they are the identical except for the above? The maven files shouldn't matter. The manifest could make a difference, but it is a long shot. You could try replacing the manifest in the war produced by Maven manually and see if it helps.