# Cannot connect to Oracle DB through Java Context method. \Error: Name [comp/env] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [comp]

Tags: oracle, eclipse, tomcat, oracle11g

I am learning Apache 9.0 web server and Oracle 11g DB within Eclipse EE environment.
When I simply connect using

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "name", "pw");
```

I can connect to Oracle DB and send SQL and receive result. (everything works.)

But when I try to connect with this method below, I get error.

```
public class JdbcUtil {

public static Connection getConnection() {
    Connection con = null;

    try {
        Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
        Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
        DataSource ds = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/OracleDB");
        System.out.println("ds = " + ds);
        
        con = ds.getConnection();
        System.out.println("con = " + con);
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        System.out.println("DB connect success! Util");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("DB connect failure! Util");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return con;
}
```

Error message is

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [comp/env] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [comp].
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:833)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:174)
at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:163)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
at db.JdbcUtil.getConnection(JdbcUtil.java:14)
at service.mListService.memberList(mListService.java:15)
at controller.mListController.doProcess(mListController.java:45)
```

So the error is at `Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");`

But sometimes error is at `DataSource ds = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/OracleDB");`

This is my context.xml in META-INF (of my current project)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
<Resource
name = "jdbc/OracleDB"
auth = "Container"
type = "javax.sql.DataSource"
username = "NAME"
password = "PW"
driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
factory = "org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory"
url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:xe"
maxActive ="500"
maxIdle = "100"
/>
</Context>
```

This is my web.xml in WEB-INF/lib (of my current project)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" version="4.0">
  <display-name>MemberBoard</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
<resource-ref>
 <description>Connection</description>
 <res-ref-name>jdbc/OracleDB</res-ref-name>
 <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
 <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

I didn't touch xml files in my tomcat 9.0 server.

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12213246/javax-naming-namenotfoundexception-name-comp-env-is-not-bound-in-this-context

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help, or I have no ability to understand it.

Comment: I uninstalled/deleted all tomcats and freshly reinstalled Tomcat 9.0 then this error went away. Hardly a solution though.

Comment: I am still very eager to know what the cause and the solution is. I spent 48 hours just for this.